# Excel 2010 - Lookup from a table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table that has a list of trainings for our field techs down column A.

In row 1 there are the names of the field techs.

Each corresponding cell in the table has either a `Y` or `N` depending on whether the field tech has completed the training.

What I am trying to do is to look through the table and find the `N`'s and display the name of the test and the tech's name on another sheet showing that they have a training that they have to complete.

Comment: Basically you need to "unpivot" your data, there are several solutions for that on the internet. After you can get the list by a simple filtering.

Comment: Please try harder to describe your problem clearly.  In the question, you say, “In row 1 there are the names of the field techs.”, but in the comment on the (first) answer you say, “I have 27 technicians’ names in B2 - B28.”  `B2:B28` is, of course, (part of) a column.  Please type in a textual mockup of your data; also, give a less vague description and example of what you want the output to look like.  Don’t even try to do that in a comment; clarifications to the question belong ***in*** the question, so [edit] the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is really what you are looking for.  But it might give you a good starting point.

Using the IF function you can pull the data from one page to another, based on a condition.  This is assuming that there are three cells per row (Tech Name, test y/n, and test name).  On Sheet2 place this in cell A1

```
=IF(Sheet1!B1="N",Sheet1!A1,"")
```

And place this in cell B1

```
=IF(Sheet1!B2="N",Sheet1!C2,"")
```

This will pull the name of the tech and the name of the test on Sheet2.  this can be cleaned up a lot more with further scripting.  I'm just not 100% sure of your layout (if you want to post a row, that could help).

Hope that helps out, either way...

--Charles

Comment: I removed your signature because it does not comply with ***[our model](http://superuser.com/help/behavior)*** here on Super User per the [help] which states **"Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings"**.

Comment: I have 27 technicians names in  B2 - B28.  Below that I have 29 different tests in A2 - A30.  There is a grid of Y and N based on whether the tech has completed the tests or not.  I am trying to find a way to display the test name and the tech's name based on the Y and N in the grid.  I want to display all of the N's so that I can have a summary of who and what tests they need to complete.

Comment: @BillBennett Can you give an example of the grid as well?  The base of being able to do it will depend on the point where you show "this tech took this test."